# Multiple files to require in 'require_relative'?

Tags: ruby

I am implementing Huffman code and need to use a Huffman_Tree.rb class and Huffman_Tree_Node_values.rb class in my Huffman_Code.rb class. I will simplify so I don't post all code. I am getting this error:

```
Huffman_Code.rb:54:in `create_tree': uninitialized constant 
HuffmanCode::HuffmanTree (NameError)
    from Huffman_Code.rb:15:in `encode'
    from Huffman_Code.rb:82:in `<main>'
```

Here is the code:

```
require_relative 'Huffman_Tree_Node_Values'
require_relative 'Huffman_Tree'

Class Huffman_Code
    def create_tree
        right_child = Huffman_Tree.new(right_child_data)
    end
end
```

This is the same error I get if I don't require_relative anything. It uses the Huffman_Tree_Node_Values.rb fine but doesn't load the Huffman_Tree.rb class. How do I require multiple classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be with your require_relative statements.  From the documentation:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html

> Ruby tries to load the library named string relative to the requiring
>   file’s path. If the file’s path cannot be determined a LoadError is
>   raised. If a file is loaded true is returned and false otherwise.

So if your files were not loading, it would error there.

You need to initialize Huffman_Code class where ever you are calling it from in order to get access to that definition.

Comment: Yep. I was calling root = HuffmanTree.new instead of root = Huffman_Tree.new. I forgot the underscore. Thank you.